# finiteness of Abelian varieties $B$ with $T_\ell A \cong T_\ell B$ for all primes $\ell$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $K$ be a number field.

In Faltings' *Finiteness Theorems for Abelian Varieties over Number Fields*, Corollary 3:

> Let $A/K$ be an abelian variety, $d > 0$.  Then there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of abelian varieties $B/K$ with polarisation of degree $d$ and $T_\ell A \cong T_\ell B$ as $\mathbf{Z}_\ell[\Gamma]$-modules for all primes $\ell$.

By the assumption on the Tate module, there is a $K$-isogeny $f_{\ell,B}: A \to B$ of degree prime to $\ell$ for all primes $\ell$.  One can assume $A,B/K$ semistable and for all $B$, there is an isogeny of degree $\sqrt{d}$ to a principally polarised abelian variety, and there exists an $N$ such that for every prime $\ell$ and all $B$, there exist $K$-isogenies $f: A \to B$ such that $\ell^{v_\ell(\deg(f))} \| N$.

Why does there exist such an $N$? Faltings is very sketchy here.

Lemma 3.2 on p. 169 of Faltings-Wüstholz, *Rational Points* may help: Let $S$ be a finite set of primes and assume $T_\ell A \cong T_\ell B$ for all $\ell \in S$. Then there exists an isogeny $A \to B$ of degree prime to all primes in $S$.

Comment: There are some hints in Milne's review of Faltings' paper on MathSciNet, but I have to think about this.